# Dúvida menu do PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Modifiquei a cor (hover) quando passo o mouse pelo item do menubar, porém os ícones do mesmo também tá sumindo, quando eu passo o mouse por cima da imagem. Como eu faço pro ícone não sumir?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 /* Cor menu */
.ui-menubar,.ui-menu-child,.ui-menu {
    background: #F0F2F4 !important;
}
```

```
     <p:menuitem value="Relatórios" icon="ui-icon-calculator"

     <p:menuitem value="Segurança" icon="ui-icon-key"

     <p:menuitem value="Sair" icon="ui-icon-close"
```

Comment: Já tentou aplicar direto no :hover ??@robsonp